# Split a string in PHP by leading char of a word

Tags: php, regex, string

I have stored an Instagram caption in a string

Something like:

```
$caption_text ="This is a beautiful photo #beautiful #photo #awesome #img";
```

My goal is to split the string in one array containing the tags and keep the rest of the string in a variable

e.g

```
$matches[0] --> "#beautiful"
$matches[1] --> "#photo" etc..

also $leftoverString="This is a beautiful photo";
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what would the result be for *"This is a #beautiful #photo of my cat. #awesome #img"*.

Comment: That's simply `$matches = preg_split('/\s*#/', $caption_text);` with the leading string in matches[0] and the other stuff behind (`$leftoverString=$matches[0]`).

Comment: @rubberboots Great! I will combine it with an answer below to fit my needs!

Comment: If you want to keep the `#`, then: `$matches = preg_split('/\s(?=#)/', $caption_text);`

Answer (score 5):

```
$caption_text ="This is a beautiful photo #beautiful #photo #awesome #img";
if (preg_match_all('/(^|\s)(#\w+)/', $caption_text, $arrHashtags) > 0) {
    print_r($arrHashtags[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$caption_text = "This is a beautiful photo #beautiful #photo #awesome #img";

preg_match_all ( '/#[^ ]+/' , $caption_text, $matches );

$tweet = preg_replace('/#([^ \r\n\t]+)/', '', $caption_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
$caption_text ="This is a beautiful photo #beautiful #photo #awesome #img";

$array = explode(' ', $caption_text);

$photos = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ($a[0] == '#') {
        $photos[] = $a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$caption_text ="This is a beautiful photo #beautiful #photo #awesome #img";

$matches = explode('#',$caption_text);

for($i = 0; $i<count($matches);$i++)
{ 
   $matches[$i]= '#'.$matches[$i];
}

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Your suggestion is not working, since the $matces array contains the tags without the "#" char

Comment: No need for worries, I have implemenented another suggestion. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to explode by " " and then check each item if it has an tag. If not you can make the others to an string again.
e.g.:

```
$arr_text = explode(' ',"This is a beautiful photo #beautiful #photo #awesome #img");
$tmp = array();
foreach ($arr_text as $item) {
    if(strpos($item,'#') === 0) {
        //do something
    } else  {
        $tmp[] = $item;
    }
}
implode(' ', $tmp);
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$caption_text ="This is a beautiful photo #beautiful #photo #awesome #img";
$new = explode(" ",$caption_text);
foreach($new as $key=>$value)
{
if($value[0] == "#")
$match[] = $value;
else
$rem .= $value." "; 
}
print_r($rem).PHP_EOL;
print_r($match)
?>
```

Comment: As the above suggestion , the code worked, but your code is slow too! Thanks for your effort anyway :)

Comment: sure, the regex method would be surely faster than this

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp = explode(' ', $caption_text);
$matches = array();
foreach ($temp as $element) {
    if ($element[0] == '#') {
       $matches[] = $element;
    }
    else
        $leftoverstring .= ' '.$element;
}

print_r($matches);
echo $leftoverstring;
```

Comment: Worked great , but extremely slow!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$caption_text ="This is a beautiful photo #beautiful #photo #awesome #img";
$new = explode(" #",$caption_text);
print_r($new);
?>
```